# JQuery - Wrap divs in groups of 50 after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html :

```
<div class="backpack_all"> //wrapper for all on screen content
    ...
    <div class="backpack"> //main content to display
        <div class="item1">
        <div class="item2">
        <div class="item3">
        ...etc
```

I will have anywhere from 200-500 items in this format. I'm also actively sorting this data by various attributes on these items. When unsorted, they are partitioned in sets of 50 by a class="backpack_partition" which wraps around 50 items. To sort them I have to unwrap all items from their respective partitions. How can I use jquery/javascript to rewrap them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resorted to some good old fashioned JS.

```
var divs = $('.backpack > .item');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=50) {
    divs.slice(i, i+50).wrapAll("<div class='backpack_partition'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method:

> Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.backpack').wrapAll('<div class="backpack_all" />')
```

or:

```
$('.backpack:first').nextUntil('.backpack:eq(50)').end().wrapAll('<div class="backpack_all" />')
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't quite do it. To paraphrase for clarification, I'm trying to wrap every 50 'items' in the div class 'backpack_partition', which will be a child of 'backpack'. Thanks for any insight you may offer, you've already blown my mind with the one liner.